Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6
I have a server from OVH (VPS) but unfortunatelly they only provide a /128 IPv6 block.
So, I decided to use a Hurricane Electric (HE) tunnel to have a /64 IPv6 block.
I've followed HE instructions in how to set up the tunnel, etc, but somehow some IPv6 connectivity is broken.

Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6

My current Config (50-cloud-init.yaml)
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
            - 2001:41d0:701:1100::750d/56
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:77:34:f9
            mtu: 1500
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 213.186.xx.xx
                search: []
            routes:
            -   to: ::/0
                via: 2001:41d0:xxx:xxxx::1
            set-name: ens3


The new extra config from Hurrican Electrics (99-he-tunnel.yaml)
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    he-ipv6:
      mode: sit
      remote: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
      local: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
      addresses:
        - "2001:470:xxxx:7b::2/64"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: "2001:470:xxxx:7b::1"

My current Warnings
* (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:54.963: Permissions for /etc/netplan/99-he-tunne.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:54.963: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6

** (generate:1887): WARNING **: 20:18:54.970: Permissions for /etc/netplan/99-he-tunne.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (generate:1887): WARNING **: 20:18:54.971: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6
Cannot call Open vSwitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:55.847: Permissions for /etc/netplan/99-he-tunne.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:55.848: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:56.094: Permissions for /etc/netplan/99-he-tunne.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:56.094: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:56.094: Permissions for /etc/netplan/99-he-tunne.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:1885): WARNING **: 20:18:56.094: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv6 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens3 but also in he-ipv6

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
